# Creating BIM 360 Project Dashboards

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

I am following the learnforge guide to create a dashboard for BIM 360 projects. When I run the code and "Sign In" to provide access, it times out and fails to load the BIM 360 hubs/projects.

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/dashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KURHv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdjLX.png)

Comment: From your screenshots I see that it actually does hit the `api/forge/callback/oauth` handler. Try putting a breakpoint on the `Redirect` line and see if it actually gets there. If it doesn't there could be some issue in the `CreateFromCodeAsync` helper method.

Comment: Also, be careful with one thing: the temporary code that's passed to your server's `api/forge/callback/oauth` endpoint is only valid for a short amount of time (couple of seconds). So if you put a breakpoint in your code *after* receiving the temp code and *before* using it to generate an access token, the code might expire.